# order of events when a DOM element event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a Javascript function bound to the click event of an INPUT element (either checkbox or radio). That function examines the 'checked' property of the DOM element and takes action depending upon whether it is set or not.

If the user clicks on the element as represented in the GUI, the state of the checked property reflects the appearance in the GUI (that is, if the user's click activated the element, the checked property is true).

However, if I trigger the click event (using jQuery), then, when the bound-to-the-click function is invoked, examining the state of the checked property does NOT show the new state. However, the GUI does get updated to present proper representation of the actual state.

Is there a defined order to when these activities are performed? It seems odd to me that the event listener would be invoked before the checked property is set.

Comment: Yes I have seen this before on input elements. The element state is updated AFTER the onclick event. I'm pretty sure this is the same in all browsers.

Comment: @Richard My demo doesn't agree: http://jsfiddle.net/g4aVm/

Comment: @Sime - checking your demo :)

Comment: @Sime - very interesting, your demo does imply otherwise. I'm *positive* I've seen this before.

Comment: @Richard It's the `value` property inside a `keypress` handler that doesn't reflect the new state ([See here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4aVm/1/)). Maybe that's what you've seen before...

Comment: @Sime -- please note that I am reporting a difference between when the user clicks the GUI, and when the DOM event is triggered. See my comment to your answer below.

Comment: @Zhami As @edeverett said, using the built-in `click()` method to trigger the event does not have this issue. As for jQuery's `trigger('click')`, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Zhami I've filed a ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9274

Comment: @Šime Thanks for filing the ticket. The ticket has been closed. The responder said that the correct event to be listening for is "change" not "clicked" (see http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/H7qry/4/)

Comment: All that said, turns out it was much easier for me to solve by invoking the click() method on the DOM element. Still, I will probably refactor my code to listen for "change" event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. The .click() called through jQuery has a different behaviour than calling .click() direct on the element. See here :

http://jsfiddle.net/g4aVm/6/

I would take this to indicate that jQuery is doing something non-standard/buggy here.

(I'm slight old fashioned and don't trust jQuery with simple DOM stuff. There's not much to gain by using a library to replicate what already exists, but that's a different discussion.)

Comment: The jQuery team says that the correct event to listen for is 'change', not 'clicked'. See Šime's ticket  at bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9274), and the JSFiddler code at jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/H7qry/4)

Comment: Hmm... not convinced by their reply. It seem like jQuery's current behaviour is going to cause confusion but with little benefit. I'd guess it's an issue/bug that was missed, and changing it now would break existing sites.

Comment: Looks like there are plenty of other people reporting it as a bug. A poor design decision that they are stuck with? http://bugs.jquery.com/search?ticket=on&q=click%28%29&page=1&noquickjump=1